# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' when running npx for tailwind

Tags: node.js, flask, tailwind-css

I am a newly self taughet web developer and I am trying to follow the steps to setup tailwind CSS flask flowbite for a new project but every time i do an npx command I get an error message. I tried to uninstall node.js completely and reinstalll the latest version and still got the same problem. has anyone experienced this too

Comment: Hey! Can you please specify the issue like where are you actually getting the error?